# AngularJs form validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new on angular js, working on form validations. I have done all but still validation doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<form role="form" name="studentForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="student_email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="student_email" ng-model="studentEmail" class="form-control" id="student_email" required>
            <div role="alert" class="error-msg" ng-messages="studentForm.student_email.$error">
                <p ng-message="required">Your email is required.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/) for this? This will help others to look into the issue and provide solutions.

Comment: Have you included <script src="angular-messages.js"> on your page?

Comment: No errors in the console ?

Comment: @garethb yes script is included.

Comment: @load , yes a very strange error. i have included the angular.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RlOtFRqsKcovPgr7hzse?p=preview) for your code.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
```

May be you forgot to add the scripts in your html files. The position of the scripts in the index.html file also matters. the **ng-message** should only include below the **angular.min.js**

Please check the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/RlOtFRqsKcovPgr7hzse?p=preview)

Comment: is it possible to hide message onload? i mean i want to show whenever we  touch that field.

Comment: Have a look at $touched

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

> Note that novalidate is used to disable browser's native form validation.

try removing the novalidate from the form tag:

```
<form role="form" name="studentForm" class="form-horizontal">
```

I hope it helps.